# Unzipping a file error?

Tags: c#

I have used this code given by Marc Gravell in SO to unzip a file

[Unzipping a file error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338934/unzipping-a-file-error)

and got this error in this line  `while ((myEntry = s.GetNextEntry()) != null)`

```
ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipException: Wrong Local header signature: 0xAFBC7A37
```

Any Suggestion??

Comment: It *sounds* like your zip is possibly corrupt... - or maybe your stream just isn't at the right place when starting. A bit hard to tell with this little context, though.

Comment: @Marc Gravell:I have tried it with winzip still i got error...... Wrong Local header signature: 0x21726152

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that hex codes 37 7A equate to the letters '7z', it looks like you've got a file in 7Zip format.

This answer may help you access it from .NET: [How do I create 7-Zip archives with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222030/how-do-i-create-7-zip-archives-with-net)

Comment: kudos for recognizing the header

Comment: I have tried it with winzip still i got error...... Wrong Local header signature: 0x21726152

Comment: You need to download 7-Zip, which is different from WinZip: http://www.7-zip.org/